# Vector with many non-zero coordinates

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, finite-fields

Given finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, positive integers $n$ and $k<n$. Given $k$-dimensional subspace $X$ of $\mathbb{F}_q^n$, for which $m=m(q,k,n)$ may we find for sure a vector in $X$ with at least $m$ non-zero coordinates?

Comment: Is this inspired from the recent solution of cap-set problem? Even though Gijswijt doesn't make it that explicit, the following is used in his proof, http://homepage.tudelft.nl/64a8q/progressions.pdf: "Every $k$-dimensional subspace of $F^n$ has a vector in it that has at least $k$ non-zero coordinates", and I found it not so obvious when I first read it. It's basically the last step where he shows that $\dim V = |A'| \leq 2 \dim L_{n, \frac{1}{3}(p-1)n}$.

Comment: Ha-ha, of course it is. (I did not know about Gijswijt and Ellenberg's papers, but reinvented essentially the same proof instead.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By Gauss' method, you may find a basis $v_1,\dots,v_k$ of $X$ such that $s(v_1)<s(v_2)<\dots<s(v_k)$, where $s(v)$ is the number of the first nonzero entry in $v$. Using these vectors, you may inductively construct a vector with nonzero entries at positions $s(v_1)$, \dots, $s(v_k)$, so at least $k$ nonzero coordinates are always achievable. Clearly, $m=k$ is the maximal value, in view of the example $\mathbb F_q^k\leqslant \mathbb F_q^n$.